# Tomita–Takesaki theory and subfactors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra acting on a Hilbert space $H$. Let $\Omega$ be a cyclic and separating vector in $H$. Let $J$ and $\Delta$ be the corresponding modular conjugation and modular operator from [Tomita–Takesaki theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomita%E2%80%93Takesaki_theory), i.e. $JMJ=M'$ and $\Delta^{it}M\Delta^{-it} = M$, for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

What is known about the unital inclusions of von Neumann algebras $N \subset M$ such that $\Delta^{it}N\Delta^{-it} = N$?
What if $N \subset M$ is a unital inclusion of $\mathrm{III}_1$ factors? What if it is (moreover) of finite index?

Ziyun Xu just pointed out to me the following theorem by M. Takesaki (in [this book](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-10451-4), Chapter 9) which should be useful here.

[image]

In fact, I would like to know whether a unital inclusion of $\mathrm{III}_1$ factors can always be reduced (i.e. keeping the *quantum symmetries*) into a unital inclusion of $\mathrm{II}_{\infty}$ factors *just* using the Tomita–Takesaki theory (and then into a unital inclusion of $\mathrm{II}_{1}$ factors using $\mathrm{II}_{1} \otimes \mathrm{I}_{\infty} =  \mathrm{II}_{\infty}$), with a finite index assumption if required.

---

There exists such reduction by Sorin Popa using Jones' tower, see the following extract from the introduction of [his book](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1339767).

[image]

But this post asks about using the Tomita-Takesaki theory *only*.